# Getting post array empty in codeigniter from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter-2

I am submitting the form data from angular to codeigniter, getting the post array empty in codeigniter's controller.
please help me, thanks.

here is angular's controller

```
app.controller('step3', ['$scope', '$http', 'formdata', '$location', function($scope, $http, formdata, $location) {
$scope.formdata = formdata;
$scope.sendData = function($event) {
    console.log(formdata);
    $http.post(api_url + '/submit-agency-registration-form', {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
        },
        formdata: formdata
    }).success(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    $event.preventDefault();
};
```

}]);

I am using factory named formdata:

```
app.factory("formdata", function() {
    return {};
});
```

I am getting $_POST['formdata']; or $this->input->post('formdata'); undefined in codeigniter's conroller.

Comment: where `formdata` is getting filled?

Comment: using  $scope.formdata = formdata; i am filling formdata, every control having formdata.index in their ng-model, like, <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.firstname"> etc.

Comment: @ user3736676, please look at the code, before post I used console.log(formdata), its printing the data on console

Comment: If `$_POST['formdata']` is undefined, have you examined `$_POST` to see what it gives you?

Comment: @ Sparky, yes i have examined the $_POST, its also NULL

Answer (score 0):

is the params in your post method are in the right order ? 
Don't you have to write it like that ?

```
$http.post(api_url + '/submit-agency-registration-form',
    {formdata: formdata}, {
    headers: {
        'Content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    }
})
```

Comment: @ Skander.B, Thanks, but it also showing 'undefined index formdata'

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
app.controller('step3', ['$scope', '$http', 'formdata', '$location', function($scope, $http, formdata, $location) {
$scope.formdata = formdata;
$scope.sendData = function($event) {
console.log(formdata);
$http({
           url: api_url + '/submit-agency-registration-form',
           method: "POST",
           data: 'formdata=' + JSON.stringify(formdata),
           headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
           }
       }).success(function(data) {
           alert(data);
       });
        $event.preventDefault();
}; }]);
```

I am catching the the data at codeigniter controller like this

```
$postdata=json_decode($_POST['formdata'],true);
```